# What is the right way to listen for clicks outside an Ember Component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have an Ember.js component called `header-main.js` with the template `header-main.hbs`. Within the Handlebars file, I have something like this:

```
<ul id="header-nav">
  <li class="unopened">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Brand</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Lenovo</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Dell</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">HP</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the component's `didInsertElement` hook, I have some jQuery that changes the class of the `<li>` tag to show the dropdown menu like this:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$('#header-nav li > a').click(function() {
    var currentState = $(this).parent().attr('class');

    if (class === 'unopened') {
        $(this).parent().attr('class', 'open');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().attr('class', 'unopened');
    }
  });
}
```

This all works great except, it forces the user to only click the button to toggle the dropdown unlike most websites that let you just click anywhere in the window to close the dropdown. What is the right way to make sure that the dropdown within this component can be closed by clicking anywhere in the window? I also face similar situations with modal windows.

Answer (score 2):

Use JQuery focusout() to define the closing action.
So whenever the component loses focus,ie.,there is a click outside, it should close.

Comment: alternatively there is an actual `focusOut()` method built in to all components.. which listen on the focusout event, and you can override to do your own things with.

Comment: yeah, that would be a more emberish method to do it!!

Answer (score 0):

This is very out of date (but it is an old question). To help future engineers looking for an answer, from EmberJS 3.28+ they moved towards using `modifiers` to handle this and other component events.

Please see the [EmberJS 5 Component Docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v5.5.0/components/template-lifecycle-dom-and-modifiers/#toc_out-of-component-modifications) for details, specifically there is an example `on-click-outside` which explains how to do this.

Note: In EmberJS 3.x, 4.x you will need to install `ember-modifier` package to do this. It is fully integrated in EmberJS 5, no additional package required.